# How to make an php web application run some injected code?

Tags: php, security, code-injection

I have an academic project that consists in exploring vulnerabilities of an web application.
I was able to see the source code of a file by using a PHP Wrapper

`http://192.168.1.123/index.php?page=php://filter/convert.base64-encode/resource=setupreset`

and I was able to see the source code of the file encoded in base 64 and after decoding it this part intrigued me.

```
nclude 'includes/dbconfig.inc';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Error connecting to mysql');
mysql_query("DROP DATABASE " . $dbname,$conn);
mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE ". $dbname,$conn);
echo mysql_error($conn);
include 'includes/db.inc';
$query = 'CREATE TABLE forum_table( '.
         'cid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, '.
         'poster_name TEXT, '.
         'comment TEXT, '.
         'date DATETIME, '.
         'PRIMARY KEY(cid))';   
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo mysql_error($conn );
$query ="INSERT INTO `forum_table` (`cid`, `poster_name`, `comment`, `date`) VALUES
    (1, 'adude', 'Hello!!', '2009-03-01 22:26:12'),
    (2, 'adude', 'This lemonade is awesome!', '2009-03-01 22:26:54'),
    (3, 'anonymous', 'I am too good to diclose my identity', '2009-03-01 22:27:11'),
    (4, 'ze', 'Working hard for ESEGI.', '2009-03-01 22:27:48'),
    (5, 'ze', 'Please go to moodle and check the profs latest news.', '2009-03-01 22:29:04'),
    (6, 'manel', 'Got to study for ESEGI. ', '2009-03-01 22:29:49'),
    (7, 'manel', 'This assignment is EASY!', '2009-03-01 22:30:06'),
    (8, 'admin', 'The force IS with me.', '2009-03-01 22:31:13')";
```

What kind of attack can I do now with this information ? Can I use the fact that some variables are exposed like for example dbuser? Can I insert some code in the INSERT statement like for example `<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>`?

How can I make the application run my edited script?

Comment: Nothing in this code makes use of parameters sent by the client. I don't see any way to inject into it. Knowing the names of variables doesn't allow you to inject anything.

Comment: but for example, I can copy this script and add for example an echo for the variables.
Would i be able to make this script of mine be runned by the server?

Comment: I can't figure out what that `php://filter` is doing. What is the `setupreset` resource?

Comment: @Barmar basically that is a PHP Wrapper, using that wrapper I was able to see the source code of the file setupreset encoded in base64. If you use a base64 decoder you are able to see the original source code

Comment: The source code alone does not allow you to inject something in a live system on a server. if so, any open source project would be vulnerable per definition. You must gain access to the server and manipulate the code there. Only the first line could be of use if there is remote file inclusion enabled on the server and you can figure out the url to the include file.

Comment: @OnkiHara is not enabled. But by seeing the source code can't I find for example flaws in the code that I can explore? For example seeing the table names wouldn't be a vulnerability since it makes it easier for a possible sql injection?

Comment: I can see in the code snippet no user input that gets inserted in the database. So there is no way to know how this is handled. Only trying on an input form of the page would give you a hint. Then the knowledge of the database structure will be useful to extract some data.

Comment: @OnkiHara this file only creates the database schema. Creates the tables and inserts data into it

Comment: You should explore other files and other vulnerabilities